# Trouble Running Access Macro from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access Macro from VBA and keep getting error: 
Run-time Error 2485; Access cannot find the object 'MyTest'
My code is below - it is odd because the line:
A.DoCmd.OpenModule "temp", "MyTest"
works (opens the module to the correct location).
The macro is a simple test one; all paths are correct so far as I can tell. Thanks!

```
Set A = Nothing
Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")

A.Visible = False
A.OpenCurrentDatabase (DBFileName)
A.DoCmd.OpenModule "temp", "MyTest"

A.DoCmd.RunMacro "MyTest"
A.CloseCurrentDatabase
A.Quit
Set A = Nothing
```

Comment: Excel used to have a "macro" system based on menu commands in cells in a spreadsheet ("Excel 4 macro sheet"). When Excel got VBA, they just decided to call vba scripts "macro's". Access still has a separate macro language, representing menu commands in records in a table. So in Access "runmacro" means something different.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the following Excel macro starts the macro "MyTest" from a module which is included in the Access file "filename":

```
Sub test_accesss()
    Set A = Nothing
    Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    A.Visible = False
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("filename")
    A.Run "MyTest"
    A.CloseCurrentDatabase
    A.Quit
    Set A = Nothing
 End Sub
```